# Confused regarding JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two classes.

```
public class Invoice {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "invoice_id", unique = true)
   private int invId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Item> itemList;

   @Column(name = "invoice_amt", nullable = false)
   private Double invAmt;
 }
```

And,

```
public class Item {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "item_id", unique = true)
   private int itemId;

   @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Invoice.class)
   @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id")
   private List<Invoice> invoiceList;
}
```

I am new to JPA.  So my understanding may not be accurate.

My understanding is that, if I save Invoice, the **invoice_id** of that instant should cascade down to **invoice_id** of all the items.

However, I see Item being saved but get `null` in place of **invoice_id** of the Item.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE!!! UPDATE!!!**

Ok so I changed the `@ManyToOne` to be a singular attribute and did `objItem.setInvoice(objInvoice)` and saved it.  However, I still get `NULL` on **invoice_id**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are annotating a many-to-one relation, but use collections on both sides. This will not work. The one-side has to map the relation to a singular attribute. In your case, it would be

```
@ManyToOne
private Invoice invoice
```

Perhaps you rather need a many-to-many relation. In this case, you will need to change the annotations to `@ManyToMany` and get rid of the cascades (they tend not to work as expected from a many-side).

`targetEntity` attribute and the `@JoinColumn` annotation are redundant on the `invoice` attribute of `Item`.

In order for the `Item` to save the id of the related invoice, you first need to set the `invoice` attribute of the `Item` since item is the owning side (the one where the relation information is stored).

Comment: Ok so I changed the @ManyToOne to be a singular attribute and did objItem.setInvoice(objInvoice) and saved it. However, I still get NULL on invoice_id.

Comment: There are just too many things that can go wrong. Looks like we have removed only some of them. Without your current code, including the code that does the setting and saving, I cannot guess what is going wrong. Please update the question accordingly or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks mate.  I got it to run.  I just had some logical error that was preventing the proper data being saved.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is your only problem, but a 1:n relationship shouldn't have a `List` both ways. If you turn `List<Invoice>` into a simple `Invoice` object, you'll at least be closer to a solution. We can go from there if your code still fails.

```
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Invoice.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
    private Invoice invoice;
}

public class Invoice {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Item> itemList;
}
```